# React Native bundle error : Module `scheduler` does not exist in the Haste module map

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, npm

In my react native project if I run the bundling command, It fails with the mentioned error.

Command:

```
`sudo react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/`
```

Error:

```
error Unable to resolve module 'scheduler' from '/home/buddhi/Buddhi/my-dev-environment/html/react-apps/mobile-64/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/oss/ReactNativeRenderer-prod.js': Module 'scheduler' does not exist in the Haste module map

This might be related to https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968
To resolve try the following:
  1. Clear watchman watches: 'watchman watch-del-all'.
  2. Delete the 'node_modules' folder: 'rm -rf node_modules && npm install'.
  3. Reset Metro Bundler cache: 'rm -rf /tmp/metro-bundler-cache-*' or 'npm start -- --reset-cache'.
  4. Remove haste cache: 'rm -rf /tmp/haste-map-react-native-packager-*'.. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```

Versions:

- "react": "16.8.3"
- "react-native": "0.59.0"
- "npm": 6.9.0
- "node": 10.16.0

When I run the same command with react-native 0.57.2 is runs perfectly. (Note that I need to use react native version 0.59.0 to get the android x64 architecture support for the application)

1. I have tried the mentioned steps in the error.
2. I tried by deleting `/node_modules` and `npm install` again numerous times.
3. Tried after `npm start --reset-cache`.

Still the issue is there.

The change as I can see is that in react-native version 0.59.0 there is the line `var scheduler = require("scheduler")`, in the file `ReactNativeRenderer-prod.js` as mentioned in the error. But in react-native version 0.57.2 it is not used.

I'm pretty sure that this is caused by `npm`, not an issue of the react-native versions. Is it?

Can't figure out why it is not in the mentioned Haste Module Map, and what exactly is the Haste Module Map? I couldn't find enough information to support the issue.

Any help appreciated. Ask for additional information.

Comment: hey, are you still having this issue?

Comment: Yes, but I worked around it by migrating the dependencies one by one to a working copy. But there is no solution for this issue for me.

Comment: In my case I had a legacy `rn-cli.config.js` file conflicting. Deleted it and added its content to metro conf. That was it.

Comment: Can this be a caching issue, I was going through this question and still don't know what is the exact problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using expo, then make sure that your `expo` and `react-native` versions are the following:

`"expo": "^35.0.0",
"react": "16.8.3",
"react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-35.0.0.tar.gz",`

Only this combination worked for me.

Comment: I'm sorry but cannot recommend to use the exact versions to anyone. They will never be able to upgrade.